# how to use a custom type as data type in another custom type in nusoap

Tags: php, nusoap, custom-type

I have developed a soap web service with `nusoap` and `php`. In this web service I have defined a custom type named charge as bellow:

```
  $server->wsdl->addComplexType('charge',
        'complexType',
        'struct',
        'all',
        '',
        array(
                'code' => array('name' => 'code', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
                'value' => array('name' => 'value', 'type' => 'xsd:string')
        )
    );
```

And I want to define another custom type in which charge custom type is used as a data type as following:

```
 $server->wsdl->addComplexType('send',
        'complexType',
        'struct',
        'all',
        '',
        array(
                'send' => array('name' => 'send', 'type' => 'xsd:charge')
        )
    );
```

Then I get this error:

```
Could not find type 'charge@http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
```

What is the correct way to use a custom type as data type in another custom type in nusoap?

Answer (score 0):

`send` object must be changed as bellow, xsd:charge must change to tns:charge.

```
 $server->wsdl->addComplexType('send',
        'complexType',
        'struct',
        'all',
        '',
        array(
                'send' => array('name' => 'send', 'type' => 'tns:charge')
        )
    );
```